# How could I modify vertical space between inst on titlepage?

Tags: beamer, spacing, titles

I think everything is in the question. My problem is that my graphic is half visible because of the 4 `\inst` I have on the title page...
So my approach to get my graphic 100% visible is to decrease the space between the `\inst`s.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[slidetop,11pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\title[ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla]{Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\author[ bla bla bla bla]{ bla bla bla\inst{1}\and  bla bla bla \inst{2}\and  bla bla bla         \inst{1}\and  bla bla bla \inst{1} \and  bla bla bla \inst{3} \and bla bla bla \inst{4} \and  bla bla bla \inst{4}}
\institute[XLIM]{\inst{1}  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \and %
             \inst{2}  bla bla bla bla bla bla \and
             \inst{3}  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla     \and
             \inst{4}  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\date{bla bla bla bla bla}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{./figures/logo_drapeau.jpeg}}

\input{./sources/headerModifications}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Which produces :

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default is to insert a space of `1em` between `\inst` items (inserted using `\and`) - see [`beamerbasetitle.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasetitle.sty). This insertion is done by a macro `\beamer@andinst` which has the following definition:

```
\def\beamer@andinst{\\[1em]}
```

You can change that to suit your needs. For example, adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\\[0.5em]}
\makeatother
```

would half the distance inserted usually. To insert no space at all, use `0pt`. Here is a minimal example where `\date` is used to indicate the vertical space inserted by `\and`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\title[ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla]
  {Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\author[ bla bla bla bla]{%
  bla bla bla \inst{1} \and 
  bla bla bla \inst{2} \and 
  bla bla bla \inst{1} \and 
  bla bla bla \inst{1} \and 
  bla bla bla \inst{3} \and 
  bla bla bla \inst{4} \and 
  bla bla bla \inst{4}}
\institute[XLIM]{\inst{1} bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \and
             \inst{2} bla bla bla bla bla bla \and
             \inst{3} bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \and
             \inst{4} bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\date{1em}
\frame{\titlepage}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\\[0.5em]}
\date{0.5em}
\makeatother

\frame{\titlepage}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\\[0pt]}
\date{0pt}
\makeatother

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner. Exactly what I looked for ! So what is your secret ?

Comment: @rhum187: Secrets? What?

Comment: It was exactly the right code lines that I need to so I assume you read my thoughts. Anyway I was kidding because I put a lot of efforts to not ask to the forum and figure it out my myself but I gave up and finally ask...